# Proving $ \sum_{x \in A} x^k = \sum_{x \in B} x^k $ for a partitioning of a specific set.

Tags: number-theory, induction, binomial-theorem

**For each $n \in \mathbb {N}$ prove that we can partition set $\{1,2,...,2^n\}$ into subsets $A$ and $B$ so that for each $0\le k \le n-1$ we have: $$ \sum_{x \in A} x^k = \sum_{x \in B} x^k $$**

For this question, I thought of using mathematical induction and binomial expansion but I don't know how to use it here.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out.

Comment: How is this even true? When $n=1$ we have $\{ 1,2 \}$ and I don't see how for any $k$ except $0$ it's possible to partition these. If $k=1$ you can't have $1 = 2$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger i'm sorry i made a mistake in translating the question to english. i edited it. i guess the problem is solved.

Comment: It's still not right though, because if $n$ is odd, $n-1$ is even, and the range from $0$ to $n-1$ is odd. So for $k=0$, there are an odd number of $1$'s to partition into equal sets.

Comment: You should be able to do a better job writing your questions. Check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for several pointers and general ways of improving the questions. Otherwise your questions will attract negative attention.

Comment: @AlfredYerger This is a relatively well known [problem due to Prouhet, Tarry and Escott](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prouhet-Tarry-EscottProblem.html). A solution is related to the Thue-Morse sequence.